HTML tel links not working on Gmail app
I have an email in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, created in Content Builder. The email includes a tel link that takes on a variable from a data extension and should enable the user to call after clicking it. The feature works on other mailboxes but not on Gmail. The issue is the same even if the number is written in normally, not passed in as a variable.
This is the  tag that I have:
<a alias="Contact Link 1" href="tel:%%=v(@Item_1_Link)=%%"  style="text-decoration: none;">

I haven't been able to come across any solutions to this issue. Can anyone help?

Have you put the close a tag </a> there? and how it doesn't work?

yes, the closing tag is there. It doesn't work in the way that when I click it, nothing happens. Only when I press and hold, I get the options to call, whatsapp etc.

Can you input examples of the variables from the data extension e.g. what does it say in @Item_1_Link ?
